# inline if else statements in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery function that is executed by two different buttons.

```
$("#btnSearch, #btnDirectorSearch").click(function () {
```

Part of the html that this function builds depends on which button was hit. I am using data- attributes to store my variables like this:

```
var div = $(this).data("str");
```

And the html string I am building depends on what value the variable "div" is.  Is there a way to do an inline if/else statement in jQuery?

```
if div = "choice1" {
    html += '<tr data-str = "str1" data-dataItem = "dataItem1" data-result-title = "' + name + '" data-result-id="' + sel + '">';

} else {
    html += '<tr data-str = "str2" data-dataItem = "dataItem2" data-result-title = "' + name + '" data-result-id="' + sel + '">';
}
```

That seems cumbersome and I'm hoping there is a better jQuery way of doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: yes javascript...sorry I was just wondering if there's a better way of doing it using the jQuery library.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

you have a syntax error

```
if div = "choice1"
```

should be

```
if (div == "choice1")
```

Anyway, the pattern you're looking for is:

```
div == "choice1" ? <code for true> : <code for false>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use `condition ? code when true: code when false`

but i would suggest you to stick with curley braces only, as it looks better and easier to debug.
one more thing , do it as below

```
if(div==="choice1"){

}
else{
}
```

use [===](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Comment: I don't know - I think inline is nicer on the eye and for value assignment much quicker to read and understand. Seems more intuitive to me anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's only the number that changes in the output, you could do this:

```
var num = div == "choice1" ? 1 : 2;
html += '<tr data-str="str'+num+'" data-dataItem="dataItem'+num+'" data-result-title="'+name+'" data-result-id="' + sel + '">';
```

Answer (score 0):

If your choices are limited, you could add a small lookup array:

```
var choices = {
    choice1: {
        str: "str1",
        data: "dataItem1"
    },
    choice2: { ... }
};

html += '<tr data-str="' + choices[div].str 
    + '" data-dataItem="' + choices[div].data
    + '" data-result-title="' + name + ... etc;
```